# Web3js interact with local truffle without metamask

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, web3js, truffle, metamask

I have my dapp that runs correctly on ganache using metamask to sign transactions. However, I want to stop using metamask and have transactions sign themselves.

I would like to keep using ganache as this is only for a demo presentation. However, I am not sure how to connect with the smart contract without metamask.

Please suggest.